# Interpret UUID Data from DSE to Tableau

Tags: uuid, tableau-api, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1, simba

Consider there is a table in DSE 4.8.3 Cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE retail.test_orders2 (
    order_id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    order_name text
)

select * from test_orders2;
order_id                             | order_name
--------------------------------------+------------
d60c23c3-15e9-4687-9088-0be402eb90e7 | hello test

(1 rows)
```

I am using **Simba SparkSQL** Connector to Connect between **Tableau** and **Cassandra**.

But I am getting the following error:

```
[Simba][Hardy] (61) Server returned error with no error message during operation: FetchResults TStatus.statusCode=ERROR_STATUS TStatus.infoMessages= TStatus.sqlState= TStatus.errorCode=0 TStatus.errorMessage="" TStatus.__isset.errorCode: false TStatus.__isset.errorMessage: false TStatus.__isset.infoMessages: false TStatus.__isset.sqlState: false
```

This error seems to be occurring because of **UUID** field - order_id in **test_orders** column family. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this via beeline?

Comment: It is working for all other fields except UUID. Also, I am not using Beeline in my project.

Comment: I realize you may not be using Beeline in your project, however this would give an independent verification of if it's the ODBC driver, or DSE that's at fault.